# Combining two tables as a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine two SQL Server tables in a view.

They look something like this:

**Table 1**:

```
Checkout Date   Get max
-----------------------
2018-12-10      1
2018-12-10      1
2018-12-10      6
2018-12-12      1
2018-12-12      0
2018-12-12      2
```

**Table 2**:

```
Denial Date
-------------
2018-12-10
2018-12-10
2018-12-10
2018-12-11
2018-12-13
2018-12-13
```

I need to combine them such that I get the max value from the first table and the number of occurrences from the second table.

```
Checkout Date   Get max   Count
--------------------------------
2018-12-10      6         3
2018-12-11      0         1
2018-12-12      2         0
```

So far my code looks like:

```
CREATE VIEW UsageAndDenials 
AS
    SELECT
        a.[Checkout Date], 
        MAX(a.[Get Max]) [Max], 
        COUNT(b.[Denial Date]) [Count]
    FROM
        Table1 a, Table2 b
    WHERE
        a.[Checkout Date] = b.[Denial Date]
    GROUP BY
        a.[Checkout Date]
```

I believe I am doing something wrong with the count but I don't know what I can do to fix it. My output looks like this:

```
Checkout Date   Max     Count
-----------------------------
2018-12-10      6       36
2018-12-11      0        4
2018-12-12      2        4
```

I don't have much experience with T-SQL. Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: I will be looking into it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to aggregate *before* joining to get an accurate count:

```
select t1.date, max(t1.get_max), coalesce(t2.cnt, 0)
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.date, count(*) as cnt
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.date
     ) t2
     on t2.date = t1.date
group by t1.date
```